# Android- put a call on hold and add new call

Tags: android

I would like to write an app that will put the current call on hold, then add a new call.  Since this can be done by manually pressing buttons, I would think there is a way to do it programmatically, but I cannot find anything in the sdk.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Phone.apk can't compile directly from the android SDK because it uses objects and methods that are not publicly available in the SDK, you would probably have to build an app as part of the "platform" so you can have access to the same objects and methods that an app like Phone.apk does.

Comment: That's too bad.  How difficult is it to create an app as part of the 'platform'?

Comment: I think it's a bit easier now, as you can now use eclipse, a few months back, you couldn't even use eclipse, as you would get errors everywhere. 

It requires a linux or mac machine, but if you can meet that requirement, its not that hard. you just have to pull down the source and run 'make' on the platform. 

This site explains more and talks about how to use eclipse with platform development too: http://source.android.com/source/download.html