# Android Transfer Call

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dalvik

Im trying to figure out a bug liad on my table today. I haven't developed much for java/android but i'm trying to figure this out anyway.

I have an android app developed by a coworker who has quit. Currently the app is operational in 2.2. But when running it with 2.3 the app fails.

Its an app that help out with transerring calls within a telecompany switch.

So what happens is this.

Person A(internal number 001) recieves a call from Mr X.
Person A answers and sais Hi yeah Person B(internal number 002) has great knowledge of this problem! Let me transfer you to him!

Person A then calls 002 on his cellphone and waits about 10(long enough for the call to go through and start dailing) and then makes another call to number 4(internal telecompany transfer command) to transfer MR.X to Person B.

This is in short what the app does by just clicking a person in the list.

First call Person B, delay 10 sek call number 4.

```
//Initial Call(002)
public void callNumber(String callnum){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+callnum));
    startActivity(intent);

    if(isAutomaticTransfer && stateString.equals("Off Hook")){
        _initTask = new InitTask();
        _initTask.execute( this );
    }
}
```

and then

```
protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Integer>{
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Context... arg0) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(delayLength);
            Intent intentTransfer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intentTransfer.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + transfernum));
            intentTransfer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(intentTransfer);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As stated this works with 2.2.

However with 2.3 i get the following stacktrace.

```
/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.phone.extra.NEW_CALL_IN
TENT dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.SipCallOptionHan
dler (has extras) } from pid 123
V/SipCallOptionHandler(  123): Call option is SIP_ADDRESS_ONLY
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=
tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen (has extras)
} from pid 123
D/CallManager(  123): hasBgCall: false sameChannel:true
D/dalvikvm(  123): GC_CONCURRENT freed 305K, 48% free 3199K/6151K, external 6585
K/6853K, paused 14ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm(   61): GREF has increased to 401
D/dalvikvm(  123): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 8K, 49% free 3191K/6151K, external 59
27K/6853K, paused 63ms
W/InputManagerService(   61): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.i
nternal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40530dd8 (uid=10035 pid=343)
D/dalvikvm(  130): GC_EXPLICIT freed 135K, 50% free 2949K/5895K, external 5959K/
7152K, paused 75ms
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=
tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster }
from pid 343
D/PhoneUtils(  123): checkAndCopyPhoneProviderExtras: some or all extras are mis
sing.
D/PhoneUtils(  123): checkAndCopyPhoneProviderExtras: some or all extras are mis
sing.
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.phone.extra.NEW_CALL_IN
TENT dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.SipCallOptionHan
dler (has extras) } from pid 123
V/SipCallOptionHandler(  123): Call option is SIP_ADDRESS_ONLY
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=
tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen (has extras)
} from pid 123
W/PhoneUtils(  123): Exception from phone.dial()
W/PhoneUtils(  123): com.android.internal.telephony.CallStateException: cannot d
ial in current state
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager.dial(CallM
anager.java:704)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at com.android.phone.PhoneUtils.placeCall(PhoneUtils.jav
a:539)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at com.android.phone.InCallScreen.placeCall(InCallScreen
.java:2667)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at com.android.phone.InCallScreen.internalResolveIntent(
InCallScreen.java:1188)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at com.android.phone.InCallScreen.onNewIntent(InCallScre
en.java:1126)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(I
nstrumentation.java:1119)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(Activity
Thread.java:1722)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(Activity
Thread.java:1734)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityTh
read.java:1742)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread
.java:117)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityTh
read.java:978)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3
683)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCalle
r.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.ja
va:597)
W/PhoneUtils(  123):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/InCallScreen(  123): placeCall: PhoneUtils.placeCall() FAILED for number '4'.
W/InCallScreen(  123): onNewIntent: status CALL_FAILED from internalResolveInten
t()
W/InputManagerService(   61): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: co
m.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406f3830
D/dalvikvm(  125): GC_CONCURRENT freed 255K, 51% free 2844K/5767K, external 2219
K/2674K, paused 6ms+94ms
```

So i thought to ask if there was a simple solution to this problem before I lay all that many hours onto this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have even tried doing this procedure by hand ( taking an incomming call, put in on hold, call a coworker and again calling the digit 4 to transfer it) same error as the app gets. So did android block the functinallity of mobile switchboards?

EDIT : This bug only affects "vanilla" android phones mad by Google. HTC Samsung doesnt have it! Confirmed case: Nexus S

Comment: Are you sure it works in android 2.2... Because this problem occurs only when number of calls both incoming/outgoing is more than 2... Check it again against 2.2 and let us know...

Comment: It does work in anroid 2.2 we have a working app out and people are using it, only people with 2.3 that cannot access it.

Comment: It looks like someone else had a similar problem - unfortunately they didn't get great answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085449/android-put-a-call-on-hold-and-add-new-call

Comment: Hi Nick, I have gotten that part working just that with 2.3 they broke it. So im trying to figure out if there is a way around it. But seems like there isnt :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that PhoneUtils (which throws the exception) already has an ongoing call that is not idle. If you look at the source of PhoneUtils (e.g. here: http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GsmCallTracker.java.html) and search for the exception "cannot dial in current state" you'll see that the conditions to throw this exception are that there is an active call.
So you'd have to first put the active call on hold and then initiate the new one.

I don't know why it used to work in 2.2 and it won't in 2.3 but I suppose they have changed some of the ways calls are handled.

Comment: Okey this is what I have found out aswell, but haven't figured out a way around this.. How would I proceed to make the person b call on hold before calling the transfernumber?

Answer (score 1):

The exception is being thrown [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java/#704).  As the Javadoc for that [dial function](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java#CallManager.dial%28com.android.internal.telephony.Phone%2Cjava.lang.String%29) describes, `CallStateException` is thrown "*if a new outgoing call is not currently possible because no more call slots exist or a call exists that is dialing, alerting, ringing, or waiting*".  It sounds as though, in your example, the call to Person B is still ringing and therefore a new call can no longer be dialed.

It appears that the `CallManager` class did not exist in 2.2, although without further research I cannot be sure what stood in its place (and why such simultaneous calls were permitted when they are now not).

Comment: Hi yes I have found out this too, but how would I work around this problem? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This bug only affects "vanilla" android phones mad by Google. HTC Samsung doesnt have it! Confirmed case: Nexus S